# Bogarting the Data Access Layer

Tags: asp.net, configuration, tfs

Situation: The dba is an offsite contractor who keeps the entire DAL code checked out in TFS. It would be nice as the front end developer to be able to add columns, and tweak procs and whatnot, without having to rely on waiting for this dude to respond to your emails to do the work.

Question: What would be a recommended solution/process that would allow for more rapid/agile development, while maintaining data integrity as well as peace love and happiness among the team?

Im getting some good feedback on Programmers [HERE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108223/bogarting-the-data-access-layer)

Comment: This probably belongs in programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sounds to me like the DBA has taken it upon himself to not allow any changes to the data access code.  There's no constructive technical workaround.  Either he works as part of the team or he does all the work himself.  This is more of a personnel problem than a technical problem.

Comment: @Ofir: Thanks! Ill give it a shot. But ill leave it here as well to see if I get any bites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general technical answer to your question (unless you can define a very limited kind of needed access, which can be supplied via an API he provides for you in the DAL, etc.).

Assuming you already tried to talk with him and probably even escalated the issue, there is probably a valid reason for limiting access (security, data model integrity, performance tuning, version control etc.).

Try to understand the reasoning behind his approach, and to better define your actual needs, it is possible that after that you can formulate an improvement to your architecture (such as the aforementioned API) or your development process. Most importantly, talk frankly about your concerns, communication can go a long way, as long as you are willing to understand the other side.

Comment: It seems to be somewhere between wanting to keep the paychecks coming his way and ensuring data model integrity. And i actually have no problem with either as long as any requests are addressed expeditiously, which at times are not. This sometimes leaves us poor developers waiting around, which is why I wanted to see what the might SO had to say. More team communication is probably the ultimate answer, but the DBA is a lot more friendlier with the PL that I, so I dont want to be bringing it up just yet